# Access: Open form while background process completes

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access program that does a lot of calculation and database processes that takes a while to run. I have tried to load a form that says something like "Please wait..." and close the form when the run is complete. The problem is that the form does not show up. If I debug, I can see that it actually does load and closes as intended. I guess Access locks the screen before it gets to display the form.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Did you try after opening the form with `DoEvents`?

Comment: Actually I think that did it. Please post as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you added a `DoEvents` right after opening the Form, the Compiler will give control to the CPU to do the processing, whilst still keeping the Form in place. Hope this helps !

Comment: Most welcome. Thank you for the Upvote and confirming the answer :)